# search textfield in tableLayout

Tags: java, codenameone

I ran out of ideas on how to perform search in table layout using textfield. I just want to match the text of textfield with 1st column text, if it exist, show the entire row containing that text.I have done it in list and table component but in table layout everything i do is just not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
TableLayout tl1 = new TableLayout(1, 2);
Container containerTableData = new Container(tl1);

for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    Container tableNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
    tableNameData = new TextArea("Table Name " + i);
    tableNameDataContainer.add(tableNameData);

    Container inaugurationDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
    inaugurationDateData = new TextArea("Inauguration Date 1");
    inaugurationDateDataContainer.add(inaugurationDateData);

    containerTableData.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), tableNameDataContainer);
    containerTableData.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), inaugurationDateDataContainer);

    containerTableData.revalidate();
}

TextField searchTextField = new TextField();
searchTextField.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {
   @Override
    public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
      String getTextAreaData = tableNameData.getText();
      String getTextField = searchTextField.getText();
      if (getTextAreaData.startsWith(getTextField)) {

      }
    }
}
```

Update 1:
To add black and white strips design to the table as in fig below:

[image]

Mycode so far:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
Container tableNameDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
tableNameData = new TextArea("Table Name " + i);
tableData(tableNameData, i, tableNameDataContainer);
tableNameDataContainer.add(tableNameData);

Container inaugurationDateDataContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.CENTER));
inaugurationDateData = new TextArea("Inauguration Date 1");
tableData(inaugurationDateData, i, inaugurationDateDataContainer);
inaugurationDateDataContainer.add(inaugurationDateData);

containerTableData.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), tableNameDataContainer);
containerTableData.add(tl1.createConstraint().widthPercentage(50), inaugurationDateDataContainer);
```

}

method to add desired style

```
public void tableData(TextArea textAreaName, int i, Container c) {
    textAreaName.setName(textAreaName.getText());
    c.setName("c" + i);
    zeroPaddingMargin(textAreaName);
    zeroPaddingMargin(c);
    textAreaName.setUIID(textAreaName.getText());
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
    textAreaName.setEditable(false);
    textAreaName.setGrowByContent(true);
    textAreaName.setGrowLimit(2);
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
    c.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x000000);

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        c.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xcccccc);
    } else {
        c.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
    }
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    textAreaName.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
}

public void zeroPaddingMargin(Component a) {
    a.setUIID("Uiid" + a.getName());
    a.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    a.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The black and white strip style in table rows appears as abov img at first but all the styles disappears as soon as i search in the textfield. I managed to achieve those styles somehow though i think it is not the standard way to do that. Is there any standard way to achieve that?

Comment: why don't you use jtable?

Comment: That's for [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) which is inspired by Swing but allows building native mobile apps for all platforms. Swing's JTable's are too desktop specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't try it but I'm guessing this should work. It will require making `containerTableData` final:

```
searchTextField.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {
   @Override
    public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {
      String getTextField = searchTextField.getText().toLowerCase();
      int counter = 0;
      boolean show = false;
      for(Component c : containerTableData) {
         if(counter % 2 == 0) {
             Container cnt = (Container)c;
             TextArea ta = (TextArea)cnt.getComponentAt(0);
             show = ta.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(getTextField) > -1);
         }
         counter++;
         c.setHidden(!show);
         c.setVisible(show);
      }
      containerTableData.animateLayout(200);
    }
}
```

Edited the answer to hide/show the entire row. It relies on searching only in the first column and on there being two columns but that should be easily adaptable.

Comment: thanks but it only gives the component or textArea that matches, is it possible to get the entire row if matched?

Comment: tysm shai, i need one more thing here the black and white strip style in table rows. I managed to achieve that smhow (tho i think it is not the standard way to do that) but when i search in the textfield, all the styles disappear thereafter. I have updated the img of what i want & the code i have done so far above. Thankyou

Comment: The common way is to just use setUIID to something like "MyUIIDOdd"/"MyUIIDEven". You will need to redo this algorithm when filtering by having a row counter and applying the right UIID to the components.

Comment: hello shai i have one issue here, if i search in the textfield and back to the main form, the hamburger menu in the title bar disappears and the hamburger menu slides to the whole width of the screen. If i again go to table form and type smth in the texfield & delete it, then the icon reappears.

Comment: I suggest using the Component inspector and debugger  to understand what happened to the UI.

Comment: In the component inspector, the width & height of menu btn is 0,0 after search and backed without cancelling the search text in the textfield.

Comment: I suggest setting a breakpoint in the code and seeing why setHidden is invoked on that container.

Comment: it is invoked by containerTableData.animateLayout(200); If i comment this out the problem is solved. But why animate layout in one form affects the component in other form? if i use f.getToolbar().animateHierarchy(100), the icon appears but the main form animate from top and bottom, before it animates left to right.

Comment: No it won't affect a component in another form. Why are you animating the hierarchy on a Toolbar?

Comment: if i animate hierarchy on toolbar,the icon in the toolbar reappears. It is hidden by the containerTableData.animateLayout in 'dataChangeListener' (above search code in ur ans). If i comment out animateLayout, the hamburger menu icon doesnt disappear but the search isnot as smooth

Comment: The question is who manipulated the preferred size of the menu item. It's hard to tell from the code you listed what triggered this.

Comment: i almost completed the app, the searching works quite good in simulator but it takes longer duration in real devices. I have applied the table search in 2 forms. One has 50 rows, here the search is ok. Other has about 200 rows, here it takes almost 20-30 sec to search first letter and so on. I debug it in android, it has no errors. In this line in above code "show = ta.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(getTextField, 0) > -1",  I replace "indexOf" with "startsWith()". It is comparatively quicker but it still takes about 10 sec to search. However in simulator it works quicker.

Comment: Usually when things like this feel sluggish it is due to UI issues, e.g. nested scrolling, Using setScrollable(true) instead of setScrollableY(true), too many calls to revalidate etc.